# XML Data parsing issue

Tags: xml

Hello in my project i need to load XML file but is shows Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1 error.

My code is as below

```
        feedxml.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("feed.xml"));
        XmlElement root = (XmlElement)feedxml.DocumentElement;
        XmlElement xmlele = ((XmlElement)root.SelectNodes("categoryList")[0]);
```

and my xml file is as below.

Answer (score 0):

Use XElement.It's usage is easy
`using System.Xml.Linq

    XElement file=XElement.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("feed.xml"));

    foreach(var category in file.Elements("categoryList"))

    {

       //you can get value and attribuets's values of category tag 
      // you can write file.Descendants("categoryList") too

    }`